# how to save array to ios document directory?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have my own type of array and how can i save this array to ios document directory. Here is my code

```
struct Patient {
        var lastName: String?
        var firstName: String?
    }
var offpatients = [Patient]()
let patient = Patient(lastName: lastName as String?, firstName: firstName as String?)
offpatients.append(patient)

for p in offpatients {
    print("offline patients \(p)")
}
```

Comment: You aren't the first person to ask this question here.  The same question has been asked tens of times.

Comment: What part of this task do you need help with? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: i have patient's info json file in array and save that array to document directory then i read it from that directory

Comment: @NeoTeo Try my posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't save struct object to `NSArray` directly and we even can't make use of any array of struct to save in Document Directory. So we need some conversions.

First of all decide the path to store in Document Directory. In this function we will pass the name of the array file to be stored in Document Directory

```
func getFilePath(fileName:String) -> String {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)?.path
    return filePath!
}
```

Main Process starts from here. Now we will pass the `Patient` array of struct in this function which will convert in `NSMutableArray` and save in `DocumentDirectory`.

```
func convertAndSaveInDDPath (array:[Patient]) {
    let objCArray = NSMutableArray()
    for obj in array {

        // we have to do something like this as we can't store struct objects directly in NSMutableArray
        let dict = NSDictionary(objects: [obj.firstName ?? "",obj.lastName ?? ""], forKeys: ["firstName" as NSCopying,"lastName" as NSCopying])
        objCArray.add(dict)
    }

    // this line will save the array in document directory path.
    objCArray.write(toFile: getFilePath(fileName: "patientsArray"), atomically: true)
}
```

So, call this method for the saving process.

```
convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: offpatients)
```

In order to see the physical file, just print the result of `getFilePath(fileName: "patientsArray")`. It will print something like this according to your system settings.

```
/Users/rajan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B8BD5017-4BD0-47F7-B840-BE9464817392/data/Containers/Data/Application/D09FFC21-D215-44C3-831B-95A470C41A47/Documents/patientsArray
```

Navigate to your generated path and you will find **patientArray** file saved in the Document Directory location.

Now in order to fetch it back in the same form (`swift array` of `struct`)

```
func getArray() -> [Patient]? {
    var patientsArray = [Patient]()
    if let _ = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: getFilePath(fileName: "patientsArray")) {
        let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: getFilePath(fileName: "patientsArray"))
        for (_,patientObj) in array!.enumerated() {
            let patientDict = patientObj as! NSDictionary
            let patient = Patient(lastName: patientDict.value(forKey: "lastName") as? String, firstName: patientDict.value(forKey: "firstName") as? String)
            patientsArray.append(patient)

        }
        return patientsArray
    }
    return nil
}
```

Just call this function and you will get your saved array back in the same swift array of struct form.

```
let patientRetrievedArray = getArray()
```

And you are done.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This shall work for you.

Use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) framework. NSFileHande will be the thing you should learn from where you can read and write the file

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C"]
let json = JSON(array)
let storage = json.description
let data = storage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
if let file = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath:path) {
    file.writeData(data)
}
```

Comment: How will this work? The question is about an array of custom structures.

Comment: The dictionaries can be added to an array which can be serialized and then written to document directory

Comment: What dictionaries? There are no dictionaries.

Comment: let patient = Patient(lastName: lastName as String?, firstName: firstName as String?) or [string: String] dictionaries

Comment: @gurmandeep I guess it's not a simple array that you processed in the answer. Its an array of custom objects of struct which is purely swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a custom object directly to a file. You need to limit yourself to either the types that JSON supports, or "property list objects".

Say you convert each Patient object to a dictionary of type `[String: String]`.

Once ou have an array of `[String: String]` dictionaries, you can either use `NSJSONSerialization` to save it to a JSON file, or use the `Array` method `write(to:atomically:)` to save it as a plist.

### EDIT:

Something like this would do for converting a Patient object to a dictionary:

```
func patientToDict(patient: Patient) -> [String: [String: String]] {
    return ["Patient": ["lastName": patient.lastName, 
      "firstName": patient.firstName]]
}
```

You'd then need a corresponding patientFromDict function that takes a Dictionary object and returns a Patient object

You could write a map statement that would convert an entire array of Patient objects to an array of dictionaries or visa-versa.

Comment: how can i convert my offpatients array to [String: String] json? `let convert = offpatients as [String: String]` is this correct?